# For real numbers $x>0, y>0, z>0$ and $x y z=1 .$ prove that $ x^{6}+y^{6}+z^{6} \geq x^{5}+y^{5}+z^{5} $

Tags: inequality, summation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, muirhead-inequality

> For real numbers $x>0, y>0, z>0$ and $x y z=1 .$ Prove that $$
>  x^{6}+y^{6}+z^{6} \geq x^{5}+y^{5}+z^{5} $$

How to show this?

I tried using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality , but without success.

I tried prepare simple form Muirhead, but I don't understand information $xyz=1.$

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I tried using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality

Comment: Show please, what exactly did you make?

Comment: I tried prepare simple form Muirhead, but I don't understand information $xyz=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$x^6+y^6+z^6\geq(x^5+y^5+z^5)\sqrt[3]{xyz},$$ which is true by Muirhead because
$$(6,0,0)\succ\left(\frac{16}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right).$$
Also, we can use AM-GM here:
$$\sum_{cyc}x^6=\frac{1}{18}\sum_{cyc}(16x^6+y^6+z^6)\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[18]{\left(x^6\right)^{16}y^6z^6}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[18]{x^{90}}=\sum_{cyc}x^5.$$